# Hide content type labels by default

Tags: 7, entities

Field labels can be hidden for a content type by going to "Manage display" and changing the labels to hidden.

However, I rarely need to show labels.

Is there a way to have the labels hidden by default, site-wide?

Answer (score 0):

I think preprocess_node should do the trick

use that in your template.php

```
function template_preprocess_node(&$vars){
  //Supposing that your content type name is "group"
  if($vars['type'] == 'your type'){
    $vars['content']['your_field']['#title'] = '';
  }
}
```

Comment: Please could you give a bit more detail?

Comment: I've added the code above, preprocess_node seems to be the one.

Answer (score 0):

Use hook_field_create_instance() to hide content type labels by default.

```
<?php
// implementation of hook_field_create_instance()
// sets all labels to Hidden for new fields
function MODULENAME_field_create_instance($instance){
  // fetch the instance info
  $instance_info = field_info_instance(
    $instance['entity_type'],
    $instance['field_name'],
    $instance['bundle']
  );

  // set label in each display to hidden
  foreach( $instance_info['display'] as &$display ){
    $display['label'] = 'hidden';
  }

  // save back to disk
  field_update_instance($instance_info);
}
?>
```

Comment: When I added a new field to a content type with this code in place, the label was "Above".